# Rotate axes titles with ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

With `ggplot2`, one can rotate the axes titles with the `angle` argument of `element_text`:

```
library(ggplot2)
gg <- ggplot(data.frame(x=1:5, y=rnorm(5)), aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(size = rel(1.8), angle = 0))
```

[image]

But when I convert this graphic to a plotly graphic with `ggplotly`, the axis title is not rotated:

```
library(plotly)
ggplotly(gg)
```

[image]

Is there a way to rotate the axis title ?

```
> packageVersion("ggplot2")
[1] ‘2.1.0’
> packageVersion("plotly")
[1] ‘4.5.2’
```

Comment: @J_F works for me (identical versions).

Comment: Ok, I have the development version of ggplot2. With the version on CRAN, i can reproduce the issue.

Comment: @J_F Hmm ok, so we could suppose this issue will be solved by the next CRAN version of ggplot2.

Comment: I don't think so, because the error remains even with the development versions of both packages.

Comment: @J_F Ah ok, I misunderstood your comment. I think I will fill an issue to the github repo.

Comment: I've having the same problem Stéphane Laurent described in his original post with ggplot2 3.2.1 and plotly 4.9.1. Is there any way to solve the issue?